# Inputting text with commas into datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, datagrid

I am using a data grid to organise customer information. This included a note section which will inevitably include commas. When saving into a CSV I can work around this however the data grid keeps splitting my text and shifting everything along when it sees a comma.

```
            string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        string colour = cbxNature.SelectedItem.ToString();

        BriefLine = txtBriefDetails.Text.Split(',');
        newBrief = string.Join("\\,", BriefLine);
        Debug.Print("new brief_" + newBrief);


        Customer customer = new Customer
        {
            Date = txtDate.Text,
            Name = txtFirstName.Text,
            Nature = cbxNature.Text,

            Brief_Details = newBrief,
            Follow_up_Date = txtfollowupdate.Text,
            Notes = txtNotes.Text,
            Contact_Details = ContactDetails.Text,
            Taken_By = txtTakenBy.Text
        };

        // Add the new cutomer to the existing list of customers
        UnProcessedCustomers.Add(customer);
        AllCSVCustomers.Add(customer); 
        HandleCSV();
        ReadCSV(FindDate());
        HasAnEnquiryBeenAdded = true;
    }
```

I have tried replacing commas with

```
"\,"   "\\,"
```

and enclosing the whole section in quotation marks but the grid still separates the words?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgCustomers" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding UnProcessedCustomers, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="326,470,26,29" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Converted?" 
                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Converted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.Converted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.Converted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: How are you binding the DataGrid?

Comment: Did you try `string.Join(",", BriefLine);` ?

Comment: @Pikoh I have "UnProcessedCustomers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();" which I am binding to in the xaml

Comment: @Madenis, yes but the commas are my problem that would simply take me back to the original textBriefDetails.text

Comment: If you are using a `Customer` class to "feed" the datagrid, I don't understand your question at all.A Wpf datagrid cell can show text with commas. Maybe the problem is your datagrid definition?

Comment: @Pikoh That is exactly what I am doing, I have added my datagrid definition in above